# Windows 11 cmd window position

Tags: settings, command-prompt, windows-11

This used to be really easy to change in windows 10, 7, etc. But now they've gone and hidden it in Windows 11.
I'm looking to change the default location the Command Prompt window opens.
For reference I've included a screen grab of the window that mocks me by seemingly not existing anymore...[Have you see this missing settings window?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99LB2.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The same question here!

Answer (score 0):

If you open a command prompt, go into settings and change the default terminal to "Windows Console Host", you will see the Layout tab in the options.
[image: default terminal application setting]

I have to check with our IT folks, because the settings (including the default terminal of "Windows Console Host") revert back to defaults, even though I have local admin rights on the computer.

Also, if I create a shortcut to cmd.exe and configure the font/layout/etc. settings there, Windows seems to ignore them--font, layout, etc. when I launch the shortcut. I used to have multiple shortcuts, with preset positions that would give me a tiled layout, with each window have a purpose (e.g. a web/app server, text searches, debugging).

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the settings for the cmd window, you have to click on the settings button to get to the settings.json file. There you can just add this line:

```
"initialPosition": "<x>,<y>",
```

You can just add this behind the `"defaultProfile": ""` line.

For more information I found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/startup#launch-position

I hope i could help :)